# Wordpress filter excerpt by tags

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Hi I am a newbie in wordpress here, I wanted to display an excerpt in my page using the_excerpt function to display all text content inside p tags only without displaying those content inside h1 & em tags.

This is how my wordpress page content looked like:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<em>Aug. 12, 2014</em>
<p>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</p>
```

This is how I displayed the excerpt:

```
<?php
     $args=array('post_type' => 'page','post_parent' => '41','posts_per_page' => 1);

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

        the_excerpt();

    endwhile;
?>
```

Does anybody know how excerpt function will only display text from inside a specific tags? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_excerpt()` for pages (post type `page`) was dropped in Wordpress 3.1

You have to use [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) to create a manual excerpt if needed

Comment: Hi Thanks,.Is wp_trim_words function can filter specific html tags from page content?

Comment: I think the best way to go here is to totally construct your own excerpt. See my answer on another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24160854/1908141)